# Android client-server model

Tags: java, php, android, html, xml

I'm implementing a client-server model for an online store. Basically I need to retrieve from the server some information like the things the buyer brought (price, description,link, self & other users comments about the article etc) showing it in the device, allowing to navigate thought the catalog, and comment resending the updating info to the server.
How can I implement that? I have thought in a web server with php+mysql for the server, querying through html post and generating the php answer as a xml with all the information needed.
Is an acceptable solution?
I really dont know how many potential user can this application have simultaneous but it could become pretty high.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should define pretty high. One person might think that pretty high is 1000 users, while another person might think that pretty high is one million users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me, what you're currently doing is pretty acceptable.
We call it `WebServices`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. Yes but for running a pure web service i'd need a dedicate server, right? I only have access to a 000webhost server with the typical control panel

Comment: According to me, It depends. for example, for my application which doesn't deal with heavy data transfer and protected data, I am happy with my shared hosting and the scripts that I have created. I haven't felt a need of a dedicated server so far.

Comment: The webservice protocol is usually rather verbose which means that you are wasting bandwidth. I would probably looks for something else, e.g. using JSON as protocol.

Comment: I also prefer JSON over everything else as far as its just being used for information passing. If you're concerned about security, you can have a manual process for it. something like a PIN system..